# Boundary conditions for stokes flow around a sphere using FiPy

Tags: python, fipy, fluid-dynamics

I have tried to solve the Stokes flow around a sphere using FiPy. To do that, I chose a cylindrical 2-D mesh (since my problem is axisymmetric). The z-axis passes through the center of the sphere, and the size of the mesh is Lr x Lz. The boundary conditions I have used are shown in the figure below:
[image]

I solved the problem above using FiPy library for Python, see the code below.

```python
    from fipy import *
    from fipy.tools import numerix
    from fipy.variables.faceGradVariable import _FaceGradVariable

    viscosity = 5.55555555556e-06 

    pfi = 10000. #Penalization for being inside sphere
    v0 = 1. #Speed far from sphere
    tol = 1.e-6 #Tolerance

    Lr=2. #Length of the grid

    #No. of cells in the r and z directions
    Nr=400
    Nz=800

    Lz=Lr*Nz/Nr #Height of the grid (=4)

    dL=Lr/Nr
    mesh = CylindricalGrid2D(nr=Nr, nz=Nz, dr=dL, dz=dL)
    R, Z = mesh.faceCenters
    r, z = mesh.cellCenters

    #Under-relaxation factors
    pressureRelaxation = 0.8
    velocityRelaxation = 0.5

    #Radius of the sphere
    rad=0.1

    #Distance to the center of the mesh (r=0, z=2)
    var1 = DistanceVariable(name='distance to center', mesh=mesh, value=numerix.sqrt(r**2+(z-Lz/2.)**2))

    #Pressure and pressure correction variables
    pressure = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, value = 0., hasOld=True, name='press')
    pressureCorrection = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, value = 0., hasOld=True)

    #Cell velocities
    zVelocity = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, hasOld=True,  name='Z vel')
    rVelocity = CellVariable(mesh=mesh,hasOld=True,  name='R vel')

    #face velocities
    velocity = FaceVariable(mesh=mesh, rank=1)
    velocityold = FaceVariable(mesh=mesh,rank=1)

    #BOUNDARY CONDITIONS (no-flux by default)
    zVelocity.constrain(v0, mesh.facesBottom)
    zVelocity.constrain(v0, mesh.facesTop)
    rVelocity.constrain(0., mesh.facesRight)
    rVelocity.constrain(0., mesh.facesBottom)
    rVelocity.constrain(0., mesh.facesTop)
    pressureCorrection.constrain(0., mesh.facesBottom & (R < dL))

    #Penalization term
    pi_fi= CellVariable(mesh=mesh, value=0.,name='Penalization term')
    pi_fi.setValue(pfi, where=(var1 <= rad) )

    rFaces=numerix.array([]) #vertical faces
    zFaces=numerix.array([]) #horizontal faces 

    #Number of cells in each processor
    Nr_in_proc = mesh.nx
    Nz_in_proc = mesh.ny

    for zfcount in range(Nr_in_proc*(1+Nz_in_proc)) :
        rFaces=numerix.append(rFaces,[False])
        zFaces=numerix.append(zFaces,[True])

    for rfcount in range(Nz_in_proc*(1+Nr_in_proc)) :
        rFaces=numerix.append(rFaces,[True])
        zFaces=numerix.append(zFaces,[False])

    #Correct pressure gradient
    pressure_correct_grad = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, rank=1)
    pressure_correct_grad[0] = pressure.grad[0] - pressure / r
    pressure_correct_grad[1] = pressure.grad[1]

    #Correct pressure face gradient
    pressure_correct_facegrad = FaceVariable(mesh=mesh,rank=1)
    pressure_correct_facegrad0 = FaceVariable(mesh=mesh)
    pressure_correct_facegrad0.setValue(pressure.faceGrad[0])
    pressure_correct_facegrad0.setValue(pressure.faceGrad[0] - pressure.grad[0].arithmeticFaceValue + \
                                        pressure_correct_grad[0].arithmeticFaceValue, where = zFaces)
    pressure_correct_facegrad1 = FaceVariable(mesh=mesh)
    pressure_correct_facegrad1.setValue(pressure.faceGrad[1])
    pressure_correct_facegrad.setValue([pressure_correct_facegrad0.value, pressure_correct_facegrad1.value])

    #Correct pressureCorrection gradient
    pressureCorrection_correct_grad = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, rank=1)
    pressureCorrection_correct_grad[0] = pressureCorrection.grad[0] - pressureCorrection / r
    pressureCorrection_correct_grad[1] = pressureCorrection.grad[1]

    #Correct pressureCorrection face gradient
    pressureCorrection_correct_facegrad = FaceVariable(mesh=mesh,rank=1)
    pressureCorrection_correct_facegrad0 = FaceVariable(mesh=mesh)
    pressureCorrection_correct_facegrad0.setValue(pressureCorrection.faceGrad[0])
    pressureCorrection_correct_facegrad0.setValue(pressureCorrection.faceGrad[0] - pressureCorrection.grad[0].arithmeticFaceValue + \
                                                    pressureCorrection_correct_grad[0].arithmeticFaceValue, where = zFaces)
    pressureCorrection_correct_facegrad1 = FaceVariable(mesh=mesh)
    pressureCorrection_correct_facegrad1.setValue(pressureCorrection.faceGrad[1])
    pressureCorrection_correct_facegrad.setValue([pressureCorrection_correct_facegrad0.value, pressureCorrection_correct_facegrad1.value])


    coeff = FaceVariable(mesh=mesh,value=1.)
    #Navie Stokes equation (no inertia, cylindrical coordinates) + pressure correction equation
    rVelocityEq = DiffusionTerm(coeff=viscosity) - pressure_correct_grad.dot([1.,0.]) - ImplicitSourceTerm(pi_fi + viscosity/r**2.)
    zVelocityEq = DiffusionTerm(coeff=viscosity) - pressure_correct_grad.dot([0.,1.]) - ImplicitSourceTerm(pi_fi)
    pressureCorrectionEq = DiffusionTerm(coeff=coeff) - velocity.divergence

    #Matrix for Rhie-Chow interpolation
    apr = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, value=1.)
    apz = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, value=1.)
    ap = FaceVariable(mesh=mesh, value=1.)

    volume = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, value=mesh.cellVolumes, name='Volume')
    contrvolume = R * dL * dL #Control volume for the faces

    sweep=0.
    #Residue from sweep methods
    rres=1000.
    zres=1000.
    pres=1000.

    cont=1000. #Checks if continuity equation is satisfied
    pcorrmax=1000. #Max of pressure correction (from using SIMPLE algorithm)

    pressure.updateOld()
    pressureCorrection.updateOld()
    rVelocity.updateOld()
    zVelocity.updateOld()

    while (rres > tol or zres > tol or pres > tol or cont > tol or pcorrmax > tol) :
        sweep=sweep+1

        #Solve the Navier Stokes equations to obtain starred values
        rVelocityEq.cacheMatrix()
        rres = rVelocityEq.sweep(var=rVelocity,underRelaxation=velocityRelaxation)
        rmat = rVelocityEq.matrix
        zVelocityEq.cacheMatrix()
        zres = zVelocityEq.sweep(var=zVelocity,underRelaxation=velocityRelaxation)
        zmat = zVelocityEq.matrix

        #Update matrix with diagonal coefficients to be used in Rhie-Chow interpolation
        apr[:] = -rmat.takeDiagonal()
        apz[:] = -zmat.takeDiagonal()
        ap.setValue(apr.arithmeticFaceValue,where=rFaces)
        ap.setValue(apz.arithmeticFaceValue,where=zFaces)

        #Update the face velocities based on starred values with the Rhie-Chow correction
        #Final solution independent of the under-relaxation factor
        velocity[0] = (rVelocity.arithmeticFaceValue + (volume / apr * pressure_correct_grad[0]).arithmeticFaceValue - \
                        contrvolume * (1. / apr).arithmeticFaceValue * pressure_correct_facegrad[0] + (1 - velocityRelaxation) * \
                        (velocityold[0] - rVelocity.old.arithmeticFaceValue))

        velocity[1] = (zVelocity.arithmeticFaceValue + (volume / apz * pressure_correct_grad[1]).arithmeticFaceValue - \
                        contrvolume * (1. / apz).arithmeticFaceValue * pressure_correct_facegrad[1] + (1 - velocityRelaxation) * \
                        (velocityold[1] - zVelocity.old.arithmeticFaceValue))

        #Boundary conditions (again)
        velocity[0, mesh.facesRight.value] = 0.
        velocity[0, mesh.facesBottom.value] = 0.
        velocity[0, mesh.facesTop.value] = 0.
        velocity[1, mesh.facesBottom.value] = v0
        velocity[1, mesh.facesTop.value] = v0

        #Solve the pressure correction equation
        coeff.setValue(contrvolume * (1. / apr).arithmeticFaceValue, where=rFaces)
        coeff.setValue(contrvolume * (1. / apz).arithmeticFaceValue, where=zFaces)
        pressureCorrectionEq.cacheRHSvector()
        pres = pressureCorrectionEq.sweep(var=pressureCorrection)

        #Correct pressureCorrection gradient
        pressureCorrection_correct_grad[0] = pressureCorrection.grad[0] - pressureCorrection / r
        pressureCorrection_correct_grad[1] = pressureCorrection.grad[1]

        #Correct pressureCorrection face gradient
        pressureCorrection_correct_facegrad0.setValue(pressureCorrection.faceGrad[0])
        pressureCorrection_correct_facegrad0.setValue(pressureCorrection.faceGrad[0] - pressureCorrection.grad[0].arithmeticFaceValue + \
                                                        pressureCorrection_correct_grad[0].arithmeticFaceValue, where = zFaces)
        pressureCorrection_correct_facegrad1.setValue(pressureCorrection.faceGrad[1])
        pressureCorrection_correct_facegrad.setValue([pressureCorrection_correct_facegrad0.value, pressureCorrection_correct_facegrad1.value])

        #Update the pressure using the corrected value
        pressure.setValue(pressure + pressureRelaxation * pressureCorrection )

        #Correct pressure gradient
        pressure_correct_grad[0] = pressure.grad[0] - pressure / r
        pressure_correct_grad[1] = pressure.grad[1]

        #Correct pressure face gradient
        pressure_correct_facegrad0.setValue(pressure.faceGrad[0])
        pressure_correct_facegrad0.setValue(pressure.faceGrad[0] - pressure.grad[0].arithmeticFaceValue + \
                                             pressure_correct_grad[0].arithmeticFaceValue, where = zFaces)
        pressure_correct_facegrad1.setValue(pressure.faceGrad[1])
        pressure_correct_facegrad.setValue([pressure_correct_facegrad0.value, pressure_correct_facegrad1.value])

        #Update the velocity using the corrected pressure
        rVelocity.setValue(rVelocity - pressureCorrection_correct_grad[0] / apr * volume)
        zVelocity.setValue(zVelocity - pressureCorrection_correct_grad[1] / apz * volume) 
        velocity[0] = velocity[0] - pressureCorrection_correct_facegrad[0] * contrvolume * (1. / apr).arithmeticFaceValue
        velocity[1] = velocity[1] - pressureCorrection_correct_facegrad[1] * contrvolume * (1. / apz).arithmeticFaceValue 

        #Boundary conditions (again)
        velocity[0, mesh.facesRight.value] = 0.
        velocity[0, mesh.facesBottom.value] = 0.
        velocity[0, mesh.facesTop.value] = 0.
        velocity[1, mesh.facesTop.value] = v0
        velocity[1, mesh.facesBottom.value] = v0

        velocityold[0] = velocity[0]
        velocityold[1] = velocity[1]    
        rVelocity.updateOld()
        zVelocity.updateOld()

        pcorrmax = max(abs(pressureCorrection.globalValue))
        cont = max(abs(velocity.divergence.globalValue))

        if sweep % 10 == 0 :
            print ('sweep:', sweep,', r residual:',rres, ', z residual',zres, ', p residual:',pres, ', continuity:',cont, 'pcorrmax: ', pcorrmax)
```

The code converges after 140 iterations. There are many lines in this code (sorry about that), but a great part of them are only to [correct the *grad* method for cylindrical coordinates in Fipy.](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/547)
Most of the professors with whom I discussed advised me not to set v=v0 at z=Lz (not sure why). Instead, they have suggested me to use Neumann boundary conditions at the exit (i.e., dvr/dz = 0 and dvz/dz = 0). I believe this is the [boundary condition by default in FiPy](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/676), so all I did was commenting a few lines in my code.

```python
    #zVelocity.constrain(v0, mesh.facesTop)
    #rVelocity.constrain(0., mesh.facesTop)
    #velocity[0, mesh.facesTop.value] = 0.
    #velocity[1, mesh.facesTop.value] = v0
```

**The problem is that my code no longer converges after commenting these lines.** The residual error of the rVelocity equation (*rres*) goes to 0, and so does the residual error of the pressure correction equation (*pres*). But the remaining criteria in the *while* loop (residual error for the zVelocity equation, pressure correction factor and velocity divergence) do not go to 0.
**So my question is: why changing the exit condition from (*vr=0*,*vz=v0*) to (*dvr/dz=0*, *dvz/dz=0*) is causing a convergence issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that setting `velocity[1, mesh.facesTop.value] = v0` ensures that the inflow and outflows are balanced making it easier to achieve continuity. Now, for this problem,

https://pages.nist.gov/pfhub/benchmarks/benchmark5-hackathon.ipynb/

it's suggested that the zero pressure correction value is set near the outlet. Trying that with your code seems to improve things,

```
pressureCorrection.constrain(0., mesh.facesTop & (R < dL))
```

whilst commenting `velocity[1, mesh.facesTop.value] = v0` gets quite low residuals. Also, setting

```
pressureCorrection.constrain(0., mesh.facesTop)
```

gets even lower residuals, but that might not be physical.

This [fipy code](https://github.com/guyer/phasefieldbenchmark-5/blob/master/problem5.py) (courtesy of @jeguyer) solves the [problem above](https://pages.nist.gov/pfhub/benchmarks/benchmark5-hackathon.ipynb/). It uses a [source term](https://github.com/guyer/phasefieldbenchmark-5/blob/master/problem5.py#L69) to constrain a cell to be zero rather than using a boundary constraint. That might also give you an additional benefit.